# MongoDB grab last versions from specified version

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I have a set of test results in my mongodb database. Each document in the database contains version information, test data, date, test run information etc...

The version is broken up in the document and stored as individual values. For example: { VER_MAJOR : "0", VER_MINOR : "2", VER_REVISION : "3", VER_PATCH : "20}

My application wants the ability to specify a specific version and grab the document as well as the previous N documents based on the version.

For example:

If `version = 0.2.3.20` and `n = 5` then the result would return documents with version `0.2.3.20, 0.2.3.19, 0.2.3.18, 0.2.3.17, 0.2.3.16, 0.2.3.15`

The solutions that come to my mind is:

1. Create a new database that contains documents with version information and is sorted. Which can be used to obtain the previous N version's which can be used to obtain the corresponding N documents in the test results database.
2. Perform the sorting in the test results database itself like in number 1. Though if the test results database is large, this will take a very long time. Also consider inserting in order every time.

Creating another database like in option 1 doesn't seem like the right way. But sorting the test results database seems like there will be lots of overhead, am I mistaken that I should be worried about option 2 producing lots of overhead? I have the impression I'd have to query the entire database then sort it on application side. Querying the entire database seems like overkill...

```
db.collection_name.find().sort([Paramaters for sorting])
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'grab the document as well as the previous N documents based on the version'? Using your example document, will all the documents being returned have the version 0.2.3.20? Or will it be all documents with version 0.2.3 sorted by patch version?

Comment: I edited my question to clarify: If `version = 0.2.3.20` and `n = 5` then the result would return documents with version `0.2.3.20, 0.2.3.19, 0.2.3.18, 0.2.3.17, 0.2.3.16, 0.2.3.15`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite correct that querying and sorting the entire data set would be very excessive. I probably went overboard on this, but I tried to break everything down in detail below.

### Terminology

First thing first, a couple [terminology](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/databases-and-collections/#databases-and-collections) nitpicks. I think you're using the term **Database** when you mean to use the word **Collection**. Differentiating between these two concepts will help with navigating documentation and allow for a better understanding of MongoDB.

### Collections and Sorting

Second, it is important to understand that documents in a Collection have no inherent ordering. The order in which documents are returned to your app is only applied when retrieving documents from the Collection, such as when specifying `.sort()` on a query. This means we won't need to copy all of the documents to some other collection; we just need to query the data so that only the desired data is returned in the order we want.

### Query

Now to the fun part. The query will look like the following:

```
db.test_results.find({
   "VER_MAJOR" : "0",
   "VER_MINOR" : "2",
   "VER_REVISION" : "3",
   "VER_PATCH" : { "$lte" : 20 }
}).sort({
  "VER_PATCH" : -1
}).limit(N)
```

Our query has a direct match on the three leading version fields to limit results to only those values, i.e. the specific version "0.2.3". A range `$lte` filter is applied on `VER_PATCH` since we will want more than a single patch revision.

We then sort results by `VER_PATCH` to return results descending by the patch version. Finally, the [limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/databases-and-collections/#databases-and-collections) operator is used to restrict the number of documents being returned.

### Index

We're not done yet! Remember how you said that querying the entire collection and sorting it on the app side felt like overkill? Well, the database would doing **exactly** that if an index did not exist for this query.

You should follow the [equality-sort-match](https://blog.mlab.com/2012/06/cardinal-ins/) rule when determining the order of fields in an index. In this case, this would give us the index:

```
{ "VER_MAJOR" : 1, "VER_MINOR" : 1, "VER_REVISION" : 1, "VER_PATCH" : 1 }
```

Creating this index will allow the query to complete by scanning only the results it would return, while avoiding an in-memory sort. More information can be found [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/).

Comment: Thanks for this, this was very helpful. I figured out the query part prior but it seems I'm missing an Index to optimize the search. Will read more into it. Thank you!